# Explicit homeomorphism $SL(2,\mathbb{C})\cong SU(2)\times\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: covering-spaces, spin-geometry

Take a look at [Gallier](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~jean/diffgeom-spr-I.pdf), pg. 207. There is a homeomorphism
$$
SO^+(p,q)\cong SO(p)\times SO(q)\times \mathbb{R}^{pq}.
$$
Hence the universal cover of $SO^+(p,q)$ is
$$
\text{Spin}(p)\times\text{Spin}(q)\times\mathbb{R}^{pq}.
$$
In particular, since we know that 
\begin{gather}
\text{Spin}(1,3)\cong SL(2,\mathbb{C})
\\
\text{Spin}(3)\cong SU(2)
\end{gather}
The universal property of universal covers implies that there is a homeomorphism
$$
SL(2,\mathbb{C})\cong SU(2)\times\mathbb{R}^3,
$$
endowing $SU(2)\times\mathbb{R}^3$ with a unique group structure. Can this map be made explicit?

Comment: Do you know about complex QR decomposition?

Comment: [Polar Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition#Case_of_%7F'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000031-QINU%60%22'%7F_invertible)

Comment: Thank you. Why does this imply that the "$R$" part of the $QR$ decomposition is real-valued? @MoisheKohan

Comment: Thanks @AHusain I will exploit that and come back later.

Comment: @big-lion: I did not say it is real-valued. What is true is that the diagonal part can be taken to be positive: This yields the uniqueness of the decomposition.

Comment: Apart from polar descomposition, you also have Gramd-Schmid ortogonalition procedure. This gives you a descomposition of an invertible matrix as a product of an ortohonal and an Upper triangular with positive diagonal entries

Comment: @MarcoFarinati I'm not entirely sure that works for matrices with complex entries

Comment: For complex matrices is the same, G-S gives a descomposition of an invertible matrix as a product of a unitary times an Upper triangular with real positive entries in the diagonal, so $GL(n\mathbb C)$ is homeomorphic to $U(n)$ times $\mathbb\R_{>0}^n$ times $\mathbb C^{n(n-1)/2}$

Comment: And begining with a matrix un SLn (instead of GLn) you get SU, instead of U.

Comment: @MarcoFarinati Yeah that's really close to home, except that I expected something like $\mathbb{R}^3$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{C}$. This has probably to do with taking $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post as answer so I can write easily.
The point is that $G=GL(n,C)$ has two groups $U=U(n)$ and $T=T(n)$=upper triangular with real positive entries in the diagonal and $U\cap T=1$. This fact easily inplies that
$$ut=u't'\Longrightarrow u=u', t=t'$$
(because $ut=u't'$ implies $(u')^{-1}u=t't^{-1}\in U\cap T$)

So, the (restriction of the) multiplication gives an injective map
$$U\times T\to G$$
Now you can hit the problem with diff.geom machinery to see that it is also surjective, but my comment was that a look at Gramd-Schmidt ortonormalization methods is in fact a (quite elementry) proof that this map is surjective.

Being said that, now consider $S=SLn$, and the restriction of those maps.
If a matrix $A$ has determinant 1 and $A=ut$ then $\det(u)\det(t)=1$. But $u\in U$ implies $\det(u)=e^{i\theta}\in S^1$ and $t\in T$ implies $\det(t)=x\in R_{>0}$. But $e^{i\theta}x=1$ implies $e^{i\theta}=1$ and $x=1$, so $u\in SU$ and $t\in T\cap SL$. As a consequence, $SL(n,C)$ is homeomorphic to $SU(n)\times (T\cap SL(n,C))$.

Notice $T\cap SL(n,C)\cong R_{>0}^{n-1}\times C^{n(n-1)/2}$ because now you need an upper triangular matriz with real positive entries in the diagonal but whose product is 1. For $A\in SL(2,C)$, you have a unique decomposition $A=ut$ with $u\in SU(2)$ and $t=\left(\begin{array}{cc}r&z\\0&r^{-1}\end{array}\right)$ with $r>0$ real and $z\in C$.

Comming back to the explicit homeomorphisms, in one direction is matrix multiplication, in the other direction is Gramd-Schmidt formula for the $u$ factor, and "$u^{-1}A$" for the $t$ factor.

Comment: The homeomorphism is defined as$(u,t)\to ut$, why is it continuous? And why its inverse $A=ut\to (u,t)$ continuous?